# React JS navigation with keyboard arrows needs user to click in page first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a series of pages with ReactJS, where I want the user to be able to navigate through them with the arrow keys, i.e. when he presses the right arrow the page will redirect him to the next page, when he presses the left arrow the page will redirect him to the previous page. This is my code:

```
const EduLabViewPage = (props) => {

  const navigateWithArrows = (e) => {
  switch (e.key){
    case "ArrowRight":
      //console.log('go right')
      goToNextPage()
      break;

    case "ArrowLeft":
      //console.log('go left')
      goToPreviousPage()
      break;

    default:
      ;
  }
}

  return(
<div tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={navigateWithArrows}>
Page content
</div>
 )
}
```

This works fine, except when the page loads the user has to first click somewhere in the page in order for the arrow navigation to work. If he doesn't click, the arrows don't work. Is there any way to get the navigation to work without first clicking somewhere?